# How to check array for a value in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to help someone out and this isn't my area of expertise so thought maybe someone can help me help someone else.

I have a field called `Master` that contains an array. I also have a field called `Original` that contains a string. I want to check if the string in `Original` is in the array field called `Field1` and then with an if statement do something if true / false

```
"Original":"1234",
"Master":[{"ID":1,"Field1":12345},
          {"ID":2,"Field1":123456},
          {"ID":3,"Field1":1234},
          {"ID":4,"Field1":12344}]
```

The array can be different each time and have a different amount of records in it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this JSON input?

Comment: Yes it comes from a webservice JSON and saves into the fields

Comment: So is the JSON deserialisation part of the question or have you already done that? If so, can you add your code so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if Original and Master would be properties of the same class and in a variable named instance then you could use Linq to do:

`bool isPresent = instance.Master.Any(entry => entry.Field1 == instance.Original);`

Obviously you would need to first serialize the json to an instance of this class.

Comment: One little thing: the conversion string->numeric is missing, i.e. `int original = int.Parse(instance.Original)`; or even better, use `int.TryParse`.